# Adding error bars to PGFPlots

Tags: pgfplots

I know there's got to be an easy way to do this, but I can't figure it out right now.  I'm just trying to add error bars to my plot.  Here's what I've got without error bars:

```
\documentclass[reprint, amsmath,amssymb, aps,]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title = Chronological Measurements of $e/m$,
        xlabel = Experimental Number,
        xmax = 75,
        xmin = 0,
        ylabel = $e/m$\,/\,$10^{11}$\,C\,kg$^{-1}$,
        ymax = 2.2,
        ymin = 1.2]
        \addplot[color = gray,
            fill = gray,
            mark = x,
            only marks]
            table[x=Num,y=eperm,y error=err] {AltData.dat} ;
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have a external AltData.dat file with columns labeled `Num`, `eperm`, and `err`.

I can get the error bars by replacing the `[color = gray,fill = gray,mark = x,only marks]` part with `[error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit]` (which is what I see others using after a Google search), but then I lose the formatting I had (it becomes a blue, connected plot with circular marks instead of a gray, unconnected plot with x marks).  Whenever I try to combine the two (e.g. `[color = gray,fill = gray,mark = x,only marks,error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit]` or `[color = gray,fill = gray,mark = x,only marks][error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit]` or a couple of other things I thought might work) I get an error.  I know there must be a really simple way to do this, but I don't have much experience with LaTeX and I can't figure it out.

How do I add error bars to this plot while still keeping my formatting of the data points?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: It works for me with `\addplot[gray,mark = x,only marks,error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit] table[...] ....;`

Comment: @percusse It's working for me, now, too.  I don't know why it wasn't working last night, but anyway -- thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was eventually solved in the comments by using code the OP listed in the question as not working.